# The number of times users have used commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need a script that will count how much the community has used all the bot commands in discord.js.
One that will count from 1 to infinity.

I have such a script, and I don't know what to add to it so that the counter appears.

```
if (commandfile) {
   commandfile.run(client, message, args);
   console.log("Today, users have written some commands there.");
}
```

Please help me.

I use a translator because I don't speak English well. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a database, specifically [`quick.db`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)

```
const db = require("quick.db");

if (commandfile) {
  commandfile.run(client, message, args);
  db.add(`commandran_${message.guild.id}`, 1);
  let dbfetch = db.fetch(`commandran_${message.guild.id}`);
  console.log(`Today, users have ran ${dbfetch} commands`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. If I created my own API for random photos (without looking at copyright) and put the API (for the command) in the Discord bot (!wallpaper), would it be legal?

Comment: I'm not too sure but there are many API's out there with random photos, cat photos, dog photos etc.

Comment: To use a photo (any of Google), you need to get copyright to them when it comes to using them on the Discord server?